# What is the difference between note, tone and mode?

Tags: waves, acoustics, terminology, oscillators, vibrations

What is the difference between [note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note), [tone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone) and [mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode)? In physics, wave mechanics and vibration specifically, do the terms note, tone and mode mean the same thing or do they refer to difference things?

Answer (score 2):

Specifically in relation to *music*, the terms note, tone and mode of vibration are related but distinct concepts.

**1. Musical note:**

Each musical note is defined (among other things) by the *fundamental frequency* of the note. The note $A$ for example has a fundamental frequency of $440\:\mathrm{Hz}$.

**2. Tone of a note:**

For most instruments the fundamental frequency is far from the only one present in a note's audio spectrum. Usually the fundamental frequency $f_1$ is accompanied by multiples of itself, called *harmonics*: $f_2=2f_1$, $f_3=3f_1$, $f_4=4f_1,...,f_n=nf_1$ etc. With each harmonic is associated an amplitude $a_i$ so that the full audio spectrum of the note can be represented as:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_if_i$$

The spectrum of these various $a_i$ gives a musical note its particular tone, timbre  (or 'colour').

**3. Modes of vibration:**

In some cases different modes of vibration are possible; see for example the [two main modes of a tuning fork](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266008/tuning-fork-clanging-mode-boundary-conditions) or the [vibration modes of a vibrating membrane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane#Animations_of_several_vibration_modes) (a drum membrane).

Comment: What is meant by mode of oscillation?

Comment: @MrAP: Hi! Did you follow the links? 'Oscillation' is really a sysnonym for vibration. I've edited it now.

Comment: Ya i did but could not understand anything since i do not have that much of a mathematical background. I was asking for a simple description of mode of oscillation.

Comment: Look at the tuning fork link and scroll down for a schematic of *normal* v *clanging* modes of vibration, for instance.

Comment: Still could not understand.

Comment: Maybe this will jog your understanding: http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/TuningFork/fork-modes.html