# How to create a standing wave that doesn't oscillate with the fundamental frequency?

Tags: waves, acoustics, string, wavelength, harmonics

Is there a way to make the string on my violin vibrate in an overtone frequency instead of the fundamental frequency?

[image]

Comment: [Yes](https://violinspiration.com/violin-harmonics-simplified-so-you-can-play-them-easily/)

Answer (score 6):

Shortening the string is one way to make it vibrate at a frequency different from the fundamental frequency of the whole string - this is how the high of the tone is change when playing string instruments (whether bow instruments like violin or plucking instruments, such as guitar.) However, in this case we are not genuinely making string to vibrate on non-fundamental frequency, but rather change the fundamental frequency or even deal with a different string (a part of the original string.)

In fact, the string always vibrates on many frequencies, with the fundamental one usually having higher energy than the higher harmonics (overtones). The distribution of energy among the harmonics is what characterizes the *timbre* of the sound, and is partially determined by the type of the instrument, its quality, the wood used, etc. (This is how we can distinguish violin from guitar when hearing it, and this is why Stradivarius violins are superior to most others.)

Yet, there exist various techniques of exciting the string are intended to change the timbre of the sound, suppressing some harmonics (notably fundamental one) and giving more energy to other harmonics. *Flageolets* are *par excellence* the method of exciting higher harmonics, and [the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_harmonic) provides a beautiful graphical illustration of the methods (at least,a s applies to guitar):
[image]

> Playing string harmonics produces high pitched tones, often compared in timbre to a whistle or flute. Overtones can be isolated "by lightly touching the string with the finger instead of pressing it down" against the fingerboard (without stopping).

There is also [discussion of this technique for violin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin#Harmonics). In a less controlled way (but with lesser energy losses) one can change timbre by plucking the string, striking it with the bow, etc.

See also: [Forced Oscillation Explained with Violin String](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/611450/247642) for the difference of how sound is generated in plucking and bow instruments.

Answer (score 5):

Certainly, you can block the string at the nodes. For example, on a guitar, you do it by lightly touching the 5th or 7th fret. This prevents the fundamental oscillation.